# Jaikuengine running locally on Windows with Google App Engine SDK

Tags: google-app-engine

Has anyone succeeded in getting an instance of jaikuengine running locally on Windows using the Google App Engine SDK and the latest jaikuengine SVN code?

Answer (score 0):

just got it upp and running - easy as a breeze...

Python 2.54, Latest svn, GAE SDK and docutils.. that's all..

//matt